# Is it possible to change the size of an array after it is declared as an instance variable?

Tags: java, arrays, object

In my assignment, I should write a `born()` and `addChildren()` method. It is forbidden to use `List` so we are allowed to use only arrays. Every Person has a array of objects as its instance variable(children). Should i put a constant size when i declare it?  For example ;

```
private Person[] children = new Person[5];
```

Or is it possible to use a method like this after creating `children[]` with a size of 0 ?

```
private Person[] children = new Person[0];

public void addChildren(Person x){
    Person[] newArray = new Person[children.length+1];
    System.arraycopy(children, 0, newArray, 0, children.length);
    /*
    * or this can be used:
    * for(i=0;i<children.length;i++)
    *   children[i] = newArray[i];
    */

    newArray[newArray.length-1] = x;
    children = newArray;
}
```

I found this code on another site when i was looking for an answer so I'm not sure if it works correctly in this situation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: Arrays, once initialized in Java, cannot change their size; you have no other option but to create a new array, as your code pretty much does

Comment: Maybe you should use a list(ArrayList for example) in this case? Instead of copying the full array just to add a last element.

Comment: We are not allowed to use a list unfortunately. But my problem is if this code works or not? I mean can i create an array with zero size and equate it to a new array with a bigger size, as in this addChildren() Method?

Comment: This will help you http://theoryapp.com/dynamic-array-class-in-java/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891395/java-dynamic-arrays

Comment: Thank you so much links are very helpful. I didn't know that we could create an array without declaring its size because i saw another question here before and people said that it's impossible. Link is here : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763347/declaring-int-array-without-defining-size]

Comment: Yes it works but it's inefficient, unless the children array is huge it don't needs any optimization.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify the size of a primitive array since it becomes constant allotted memory. What you're doing is just creating a new array, copying the previous array's elements and then passing the reference. If you can't use ArrayLists or more advanced Collections then you can't change it.

Comment: So do you mean this method won't work? Is length of the children array still going to be zero, after calling this method? I can't try this right now ,because rest of my code is not complete yet that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Test your method yourself. :)
Just create a new array, copy the elements and pass the reference.

Comment: I just tested it in a different project and it seems like it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Given the constraint that one can't use a `List`, the approach of creating a new array and copying elements over is correct but the way you're doing it currently is not optimized. I suggest you to increase the array size by some factor to avoid the array copy at every addition.

Here's a simple implementation that increases the array size by half of its current size every time it runs out of storage space. The `size` tells you the current number of "valid" elements such that the actual data array spans from index `0` to `size-1`.

```
private int size = 0;

private int capacity = 10;
private Person[] children = new Person[capacity];

private static final float factor = 0.5f;

public void addChildren(Person x) {
    if (size == capacity) {
        capacity += (int) (capacity * factor);
        Person[] newArray = new Person[capacity];
        System.arraycopy(children, 0, newArray, 0, size);
        children = newArray;
    }
    children[size++] = x;
}
```